# Start web server environnement with docker

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, apache2

I am new in docker and i would like to know how to have a web server environnement with docker.

What  i need :

PHP
HTTPD, NGINX

I have installed docker on Debian 9.4 and iam able to run docker commands now.

I have issued `docker pull php` and `docker pull nginx`.

I have a application running on a lamp server (Debian 7) actually
All my application is on `/var/www/application`

How to create docker containers for my project ? (NGINX, PHP)

Does i need a dockercompose file ? How to write it for my need ?
Does i need a dockerfile ? How to write it for my need ?

Can u please guide me a bit ;)

Thanks in advance to the community.

In future i would like to export my application on AWS Elasticbeanstalk.
Database i will use is stored on AWS cloud (Amazon RDS) so i don't need a container for database.

Comment: you should take a look about docker file and docker compose files all over the internet, I've started docker this month and i've been able to learn a lot a things already - Docker hub is your friend, you could also take a look at this repository : https://github.com/maxpou/docker-symfony

Comment: You mention HTTPD(apache) AND NginX. If you don't mind which, I have a pre configured LAMP stack here. https://github.com/delboy1978uk/lamp Just drop the files in your poroject, `docker-machine start`, `eval $(docker-machine env)`, and `docker-compose up`, and you are ready to rock! XDebug and mailhog also installed

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to use docker-compose. this is a sample LEMP:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
web:
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  volumes:
    - ./your_project:/your_project
    - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  links:
    - php

php:
  build: .
  volumes: 
    - ./your_project:/your_project
  links:
    - mysql

mysql:
  image: mysql:latest
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment: 
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:fpm

RUN apt-get update

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysql mysqli

RUN echo "localhost localhost.localdomain" >> /etc/hosts
```

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name your.domain;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /your_project;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```